# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 during a migration in Laravel

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I am using Laravel 6. I want to run my migration files but during the migration of my "create_users_table" file appears the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create tab
le `thenewmeetingapp`.`#sql-f3c_b8` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table 
`users` add constraint `users_permission_id_foreign` foreign key (`permission_id`) references `permissions` (`id`))
```

I think the error is between the table "users" and the table "permissions" (every user must have a permission and every permission could have many users).
However the table "users" is related even with the table "meeting_user" that is a joined table with the table "meetings".

**users:**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surname');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->bigInteger('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->enum('is_active', array(0, 1))->default(1);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions');

        });
```

**permissions:**

```
Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**meeting_user:**

```
Schema::create('meeting_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('meeting_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('meeting_id')->references('id')->on('meetings')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

The migration of the users table is the first migration to be run. However I tried also to run before the migration of the permissions table and after the user's one but nothing changed. The error was the same.
Is someone able to help me?

Comment: Does your second table `permissions` has its `id` field and is it an identity field?

Comment: Ok, you have to run first the `permissions` migration, second the `users` migration, then `meetings`, and last the `meeting_user`. Note you can change the order, changing the timestamp on the filename, and runing `composer dump-autoload` before run the migrations

Comment: I tried running first the permission migration with the command `php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/test/` but it didn't work... I created only the migrations table. With your technique changing the timestamps and so the order  it works correctly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the other table your foreign key on `users` points to, `permissions`, created before you can add the key to `users`. So this particular migration that creates the `users` table can NOT be first. The other table, `permissions`, has to exist before you can reference it.

If you can't reorder these migrations you can remove the foreign key part from the `users` migration. Then create a new migration that alters the `users` table and adds the foreign key; which would now (via timestamp) run after the `permissions` table migration.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @lagbox's answer, you cannot create a foreign key to a column in a table that does not yet exist.
So, the approach I propose is that you change the order of the migrations, changing the timestamp of the file name of each migration, so that they are executed in the following order:

1. `permissions`
2. `users`
3. `meetings`,
4. `meeting_user`

Note that after changing the file names, you must run `composer dump-autoload` before running the migrations again.